# Algorithm to parse an equation (string ) and find the derivative (string)

Tags: derivatives, algorithms

Is there any algorithm to make a computer parse an function (a string) and then find a derivative of such equation (string)?
I know is a really complicated subject, if there is any material related to the subject (website, textbook, ecc...) can anyone point out to me such material?
I would like to get something like this:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D(sin(x%2B2))
Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: See [GNU libmatheval](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmatheval/) and [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.2).

Comment: It is indeed complicated. Google https://www.google.com/search?q=symbolic+differentialtion++&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 for a variety of links with different levels of complexity.

Comment: Trust me, I searched for DAYS on google, and nothing came up

Comment: The naive thing to do is first create a recursive algorithm to parse the expression in a degenerate tree. So if your input is $sin(x+2)$ your tree would look like the function sin as a root, a degenerated node as the "+" and two childs "2" and "x".

when you have that, is a matter of coding the basic rules of differentiation: Chain rule, product rule and linearity. The important thing then is to create a parser first.